# How to verify if a list is sorted?

Tags: list, clojure, sorting

How can I, in Clojure, verify is a list of numbers is sorted?

```
(def my-list (list 1 2 3 1 4 2 2 4))
```

`sorted?` only returns true if the collection implements the `sorted` interface. I was looking for a `reduce` operation that would iterate the list pairwise, such as `(reduce < my-list)`.
I understand I could manually create pairs and compare these:

```
(letfn [(pair [l] (if (= (count l) 2) (list l) (cons (take 2 l) (pair (rest l)))))]
    (every? #(apply < %) (pair my-list)))
```

But that seems unnecessarily complex. It really seems to me as if I'm missing a basic function.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The simplest solution:

`(apply <= mylist)`

`>=` also works for reverse sorting

Comment: Watch out for the case where `mylist` is empty; you get an ArityException.  Easy fix: `(defn ordered? [xs] (or (empty? xs) (apply <= xs)))`

Answer (score 5):

I would do a single pass over overlapping pairs of numbers and check they are `<=` (as you mention) because it is O(n), though you don't need to manually make pairs.

```
user> (partition-all 2 1 [1 2 3 4 5 6])
((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (5 6) (6))

user> (every? #(apply <= %) (partition-all 2 1 [1 2 3 4 6 5]))
false

user> (every? #(apply <= %) (partition-all 2 1 [1 2 3 4 5 6]))
true
```

Comment: I picked noisesmith's answer with the simple `(apply <= list)`, but thanks for your answer as well! I wasn't yet aware of partition-all!

Comment: There's no real reason to use `partition-all` rather than just `partition` when `step` is 1.

Comment: Thats true, I personally feel that partition-all should be the default so I make a habit of using it by default unless someone explicitly wants to drop data.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the list and compare it to the original:

```
(= my-list (sort my-list))
```

Example:

```
> (def my-list (list 1 2 3 1 4 2 2 4))
#'sandbox3825/my-list

> (= my-list (sort my-list))
false

> (def my-list (list 1 2 3 4))
#'sandbox3825/my-list

> (= my-list (sort my-list))
true
```

Comment: I thought about that, but a sort operation seems fairly expensive just to do. I assume since Clojure must compare both the original and the sorted list from first to last, there's no way for Clojure to really be lazy about this... correct?

Comment: Depending on the algorithm a sort operation on a sorted list should be fairly cheap. What algorithm _is_ being used here?